# Android studio : gradle project sync failed

Tags: android, gradle

im studying android development for a month
and in my project the gradle version is

code:

```
  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha3'
```

today when i lunched to android studio i got the error
"Plugin is too old, please update to a more recent version, or set ANDROID_DAILY_OVERRIDE environment variable to..."

what should i do?
how to update for the latest version gradle?.
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like alpha6 is out now - https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.android.tools.build.gradle/view

Answer (score 0):

I think you have update you sdk and tool, so try the new plugin, maybe alpha4 to alpha6 version:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha5'
```

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem you can find version of gradle here:

```
https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.android.tools.build.gradle/view
```

and change the version to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'
```

also  you have error importing this version you can change the version of grader home in gradle-wrapper.properties to:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.12-all.zip
```

rebuild project and it should work